# Static keyword doesn't work inside PHP generator function

Tags: php, function, static, generator

It seems that the `static` keyword does not work inside generator functions?
In PHP 5.5:

```
function static_fn () {
    static $p = 0;
    echo "\nstatic_fn: p = " . $p . "\n" ;
    $p++;
}
echo "calling static_fn()\n";
static_fn();
echo "calling static_fn()\n";
static_fn();

function static_gen() {
    static $p = 0;
    echo "\nstatic_gen: p = " . $p . "\n" ;
    yield $p;
}

echo "calling static_gen()\n";
foreach(static_gen() as $stuff) {
    echo $stuff . "\n";
}

echo "calling static_gen()\n";
foreach(static_gen() as $stuff) {
    echo $stuff . "\n";
}
```

I get the result

```
calling static_fn()

static_fn: p = 0
calling static_fn()

static_fn: p = 1
calling static_gen()

static_gen: p = 0
0
calling static_gen()

static_gen: p = 0
0
```

That is, the `static` keyword worked successfully for the `static_fn` function which returned 0 and 1 from consecutive calls, but it did not work for the `static_gen` function where it was reinitialised to 0 in each call.

Does anyone know why this is so, and how one might work around it to replicate static variables in a generator?

Comment: `static $p` is unique for each function, keep that in mind!

Comment: you'd better use global var or wrap your functions into class

Comment: `where it was reinitialised to 0 in each call` but you also have nothing done with the variable within  `static_gen`! What do you expect?

Comment: LOL what an idiot I am. You are dead right of course. This is an absoultely shameful error to have missed. Would you like to post an answer to this question so I can mark you correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function static_gen() {
    static $p = 0; #initialised
    while ($p < 10) { #yield while $p is smaller than 10
      $p++; #increased
      echo "\nstatic_gen: p = " . $p . "\n" ;
      yield $p; #yield value 
    }
}
```

That will work.

Sidenote: A generator function must yield values as long as values are given. So the function must provide it in one or a other way.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @JustOnUnderMillions have commented above, static vars aren't shared among functions.

Static variables has scope per function. 
Moreover, generators is not aimed to do what you've did (okay, maybe you are just testing something :)).

Anyway you could change you `static_gen()` to:

```
function static_gen()
{
    static $p = 0;

    echo "\nstatic_gen: p = " . $p . "\n";

    yield $p++;
}
```

But again, it's is so weird.

Comment: Dont let this be a example-code. This goes straight into a infinite loop!